# Using margins with strings on x-axis not working

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

I'm trying to plot this dataframe:

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 
                    'time':["12:00", "1:00", "2:00", "3:00", "4:00", 
                           "5:00", "6:00", "7:00", "8:00"]})
    time    x
0   12:00   1
1   1:00    2
2   2:00    3
3   3:00    4
4   4:00    5
5   5:00    6
6   6:00    7
7   7:00    8
8   8:00    9
```

When I plot this using:

```
myplot = mydf.plot(x="time", style="o", figsize=(10,6), markersize=13);
myplot.margins(.5,.5)
```

some data points are still stuck against the edges. There doesn't seem to be any margin.

Is it because my xlabels are strings? How should I go about this? It seems like using strings for time indexing is just going to lead to a lot of trouble.

Comment: Hmm. It's adjusting the y-margins, but not that x-margins :/

Comment: It is? It doesn't seem to be adjusting either for me.

Comment: Yeah it's adjusting the y-margins for me (I noticed because I changed the value from 0.0 to 1.0 and saw the change).

Comment: Ah, I had a `ylim` set in my code that I'm running. That seems to prevent the ymargin from changing...